# number of combinations of n A elements and m B elements

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any formula to know the number of combinations of n A elements and m B elements. I mean in the final combination A has to appear n times and B m times. So there will be always n+m items.

Im not a mathematician and english isn't my first lenguage so i apologize for my explanation.

Example:
n=2
m=3

combinations=
AABBB
ABABB
ABBAB
ABBBA
BAABB
BABAB
BABBA
BBAAB
BBABA
BBBAA
=10

Comment: It's $\binom{n+m}{n}=\frac{(n+m)!}{n!m!}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is $\binom{n+m}{n}=\binom{n+m}{m} = \frac{(n+m)!}{n!m!}$; see [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). You can imagine there are $n+m$ empty slots, and you need to chose $n$ of them to place the As (hence "$n+m$ choose $n$"), and the rest of the slots will be filled with the Bs.